# Hyperledger Composer configured with LDAP server fails authentication with error "email is missing from the user profile"

Tags: rest, ldap, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, openldap

I have configured an open LDAP and have added a few users in it, I was able to successfully log in these users , Now I have started the Hyperledger Composer Rest server and LDAP is configured as passport strategy using composer providers  environment variables. I have not configured email id as a mandatory field but I can only authenticate users which have an email id provided in their LDAP profile. and for the rest for users i get an error 500.

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "message": "email is missing from the user profile"
    }
}
```

If I add the email id field in this user account i will be able to successfully login.

I have attached the User profile configuration used in LDAP.
[image: Ldap User Configuration]

I am Using postman to post a request to my rest server which redirects me to auth/ldap.
Composer Providers provided:

```
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
    "ldap": {
   "provider": "ldap",
   "authScheme": "ldap",
   "module": "passport-ldapauth",
   "authPath": "/auth/ldap",
   "successRedirect": "http://192.168.255.104:8080/auth/account",
   "failureRedirect": "/ldap",
   "session": true,
"json": true,
   "LdapAttributeForLogin": "cn",
   "LdapAttributeForUsername": "cn",
    "server": {
    "url": "ldap://192.168.255.104:389",
    "bindDN": "cn=admin,dc=hsc,dc=com",
    "bindCredentials": "hsc321",
    "searchBase": "ou=users,dc=hsc,dc=com",
    "searchFilter": "(cn={{username}})"
  }
}
}'
```

Is the email if mandatory feild while using passport-ldap authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is required for the `passport-ldapauth` strategy to work (as opposed to Composer REST server).  Suggest to modify/add a user (from an LDIF file with mail defined) eg `mail: nwd@hsc.com`

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=hsc,dc=com -W -f add_user.ldif    // or ldapmodify
```

then try a curl (or postman as you wish) command to see if works:

```
curl -i -r -X POST http://localhost:3000/auth/ldap -H " Content-Type:application/json " -d ' {"username": "nd", "password":"nd" }
```

you should get the cookie.